# linear programming to represent mid-range

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

if we assume that x is a sorted list, why is the mid-range problem can be solved by solving : $$ \min_{y} \max_{i} |y-x_i| $$

I had difficulty understanding how the solution to this minmax problem is the mid-range of a dataset.

I conducted several lists of x for this and get the mid-range but couldn't figure out the logic behind this

Answer (score 0):

The optimization problem states that you want to find $y$ that minimizes the maximal distance between $y$ and all the $x_i$'s.

For simplicity, assume that $x_1,\ldots,x_n,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and assume that $x_1<x_2<\dots<x_n$. If you pick $y>x_n$ or $y<x_1$, clearly this is not a good choice as we can reduce the maximum distance by decreasing or increasing $y$, respectively. The maximum distance is, in this case, either $y-x_1$ or $x_n-y$, respectively.

So, now we can repeat that and place $y$ such as $x_{n-1}<y<x_n$ or $x_1<y<x_2$. But here also, we can reduce the maximum distance by decreasing or increasing $y$, respectively. The maximum distance is, again, either $y-x_1$ or $x_n-y$, respectively.

So, in the end, we see that what matters are the extremal values $x_1$ and $x_n$ and  the point $y$ that minimizes the maximum distance between $y$ and $x_1$ and $y$ and $x_n$ is simply the point $y$ that makes those distances equal with each other. In other words, the point $y$ that minimizes the maximum distance between $y$ and $x_1$ and $y$ and $x_n$ is simply $(x_1+x_n)/2$.

Comment: thank you! this makes so much more sense now!